# Adding Checkbox in Kendo Spreadsheet

Tags: jquery, razor, kendo-ui

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a checkbox to a cell in a Kendo Spreadsheet? From what I have been finding it doesn't seem like the cells do not allow template columns like the Kendo Grid does. If anyone can provide any kind of way to add a template cell or checkbox to a spreadsheet it would be awesome. I am using Razor syntax but will be willing to switch to jQuery if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: "The Kendo UI Spreadsheet widget does not support checkboxes or link buttons to be embedded in its cells" - from Progress Telerik